# change boundary to theta

Tags: integration, derivatives, arc-length

$y=1-x^2$, 
find length of curve in first quadrant

$\int ds= \int \sqrt{ (dx^2+dy^2)}=\int \sqrt{ (1+dy^2)}dx$

$\int_{0} ^1\sqrt{1+(-2x)^2}=\sqrt{1+4x^2}=\sqrt{4({\frac{1}{4}+x^2})}=2\sqrt{({\frac{1}{4}+x^2})}$

$x=\frac{1}{2}tan \theta$

$\frac{dx}{d\theta}=\frac{1}{2}cos \theta$

$\int_{0} ^{tan^-2}2\sqrt{({\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}tan^2\theta})}\frac{1}{2}sec^2 \theta d\theta$= $\frac{1}{2}sec ^3\theta d\theta$

is this right?
and also when i changed to $\theta$, is the boundary right? 
i got very nice integral but the boundary is bad

Comment: @D.B. $x=\frac{1}{2}sin \theta => 2=sin \theta => \theta= sin^{-1} 2x$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Vik, I was being too careless.  The problem is first that your are choosing $x = (1/2)\sin(\theta)$.  But this way, $x$ has a max of only $1/2$, when we need it to reach all the way to $1$.  Plus, your integration is wrong.  You are trying to say that $1+\sin^2(x) = \cos^2(x)$, when the correct expression is $1-\sin^2(x) = \cos^2(x)$.  I would recommend that you use the Pythagorean identity with $\sec$ and $\tan$ for the trig substitution. $$1+\tan^2(\theta) = \sec^2(\theta)$$.

Comment: i edited mine, still the boundary bad and the integral also bad. am i right?

Comment: No, $\tan^{-1}(2)$ is perfectly well defined. Looks good!

Comment: i got $\frac{secx tan x+ln|secx+tanx|}{2}$ from $0$ to $tan^{-1} 2$, how can you substitute it?

Comment: What do you mean?  You have the answer.  Now just use fundamental theorem of calculus:  plug in $\tan^{-1}(2)$ for x and subtract from this the result when you substitute $0$ for $x$.

Comment: yes i mean can you get exact number after substituted? $sec(tan^{-1}2)$ or the answer will be in this form?

Comment: I don't think you can simplify it further.